# Probability distrubution and expectation

Tags: probability

I am currently working on a particular exercise and seem to have difficulties figuring out what is a correct answer.

i am new to this topic, but i choose the following approached and would like to get your feedback if i am not doing it correct:

2. $E(X)$ i am not sure how to do, only had a formula $E(X)=\sum xP(X=x)$ in mind
3. $P(Y>150)=(i-p)^Y$   ? (P - probability) , i just found this formula as well, but do not fully understand what i should do

Answer (score 1):

For $k$ people to be interviewed, it follows that $k-1$ failed and the last one was successful. Hence
$$
P(X-k)=\frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{k-1}\quad (k\geq 1)
$$
It follows that $X$ is geometrically distributed with probability of success $1/7$. In particular $EX=7$. Since $Y=30X$, it is the case that $Y>150$ is equivalent to $X>5$ so
$$
P(Y>150)=P(X>5)
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot! However just to be sure, how did you compute E(X)?

Comment: E(X)=1/p is the formula you used?

Comment: Yes that's one way

Comment: Thank you ! Should i use the formula P(Y>5)=(1-p)^y to compute?

Comment: You can use the fact that in general if $X$ is geometrically distributed with probability of success $p$ then $P(X>k)=(1-p)^k$. In your case $k=5$ and $p=1/7$.